# Compare LocalDateTime with long

Tags: java, timestamp, java-time, datetime-comparison

I have a timestamp (ts1) stored in a long, expressed in nanos since epoch.
I want to be able to compare it with another timestamp (ts2), which I know is for today 8am

The aim is to know if ts1 is after or before ts2.

I have ts2 as below:

```
LocalTime eight = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Milan"));
LocalDateTime ts2 = LocalDateTime.of(today, time);
```

How can I compare ts2 with ts1 which is a long?

Comment: you can use [compareto](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#compareTo(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)) `ts2.compareTo(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(timestamp, ZoneId.of("Europe/Milan")));` 

or [isbefore](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)) 
or [isAfter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime))

Comment: Such a comparison does not make sense in itself since the former is a point in time and the latter a date and time of day. Neither contains a time zone, but we would have needed one to interpret the two in relation to each other. You may want `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome")) .with(LocalTime.of(8, 0)) .toInstant() .isBefore(Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, ts1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` are time zone agnostic. They only accept one in the `now()` factory to resolve the date in the specified zone, but then the time zone is discarded, so there's no way to convert it back to a particular timestamp. If you construct a `ZonedDateTime` instead, you can then adjust the time and extract the timestamp like this:

```
long ts2 = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Milan"))
        .withHour(8)
        .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)
        .toInstant()
        .toEpochMilli();
```

Answer (score 2):

## Comparing the current date & time in Milan with 8 AM today in Milan.

> timestamp (ts1) stored in a long, expressed in nanos since epoch

Assuming you mean the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z, derive a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 0 , myNanos ) ;
```

> another timestamp (ts2), which I know is for today 8am

Determining "today" requires a time zone. For any given moment, both the date and time-of-day vary around the globe by time zone.

By the way, your Question’s time zone `Europe/Milan` does [not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). I don't know much about [Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italy), but I assume you really want `Europe/Rome`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Rome" ) ;
ZonedDateTime nowInMilan = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

We can move to another moment using the [`with`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with(java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster)) method. Pass a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) object for 8 AM. All parts of time-of-day will be replaced: hour, minute, second, & fractional second.

```
ZonedDateTime eightAmTodayInMilan = nowInMilan.with( LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 ) ) ;
```

> compare it

You can compare moments using the [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime)), `isBefore`, and `isEqual` methods.

```
boolean nowIsAfter8AmInMilan = nowInMilan.isAfter( eightAmTodayInMilan ) ;
```

Alternatively, you could calculate elapsed time as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). Then check if negative or positive.

```
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( eightAmTodayInMilan  , nowInMilan  ) ;
boolean nowIsBefore8AmInMilan = elapsed.isNegative() ;
```

## `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment

The `LocalDateTime` represents a date with a time-of-day, no more, no less. This class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Without the context of a zone/offset, an instance of `LocalDateTime` is inherently ambiguous. We don't know if noon on the 23rd of this January means noon in Tokyo, noon in Toulouse, or noon in Toledo Ohio US — three very different moments, each several hours apart.

For the problem stated in this Question, I would not involve `LocalDateTime`.

## The *Y2262* problem

I would suggest you find another way to represent a moment as a count of nanoseconds.

The main reason is that such a count is inherently ambiguous and error-prone. Since no human can read such a number as a date and time, logging and debugging are complicated.

Also, beware of the *Y2262* problem. Assuming your epoch reference is first moment of 1970 in UTC, then counting nanos limits your future 2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775807Z. That is sufficient for current business purposes, but what if your app is still running in a few centuries?

```
Instant.EPOCH.plus( Duration.ofNanos( Long.MAX_VALUE ) )
```

Generally best to exchange date-time values as text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Those formats are designed to be readable both by machine and by humans across cultures.

Comment: Interesting, I was looking for something like `with()` but didn't realize LocalTime was a TemporalAdjuster.

Comment: @OleV.V. Doesn't work for me either in Java 8, but I figured I need to update my timezone data.

Comment: @OleV.V. I like that middle one, `ofEpochSecond` — clever, concise, and clear. Now in the Answer.

Comment: @shmosel It’s not that often needed, but there are occasions like this where it is really nifty that each date-time object in java.time also works as a temporal adjuster. It’s nothing special for `LocalTime`, it’s general for the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
    Long ts1 = 123l;
    // Convert ts1 to an Instant
    long nanosInSecond = 1000000000L;
    Instant instantTs1 = Instant.ofEpochSecond(ts1 / nanosInSecond, ts1 % nanosInSecond);

    // Create ts2 from LocalDateTime
    LocalTime eight = LocalTime.of(8, 0);
    String zoneId = "Europe/Milan";
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of(zoneId));
    LocalDateTime ts2 = LocalDateTime.of(today, eight);
    Instant instantTs2 = ts2.atZone(ZoneId.of(zoneId)).toInstant();

    
    if (instantTs1.isBefore(instantTs2)) {
        System.out.println("ts1 before ts2");
    } else if (instantTs1.isAfter(instantTs2)) {
        System.out.println("ts1 after ts2");
    } else {
        System.out.println("equal");
    }
```

Comment: Not bad. The conversion from nanos using explicit division and modulo is too manual for my taste. You may just do `Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, ts1)`, the method will perform the operations for you, and you don’t need the `nanosInSecond` constant. And a dumb detail, indicate a long with an uppercase `L` since a lower case `l` as in `123l` is terribly easy to misread for digit `1`.